# Verification Expired. Check the checkbox again - reCaptcha in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, recaptcha, vue-recaptcha

I am using [vue-recaptcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-recaptcha) in one of the application and it is attached to a form. I have the following code:

```
<vue-recaptcha ref="recaptcha" @verify="onVerify" @expired="onExpired" :sitekey="recaptchaSiteKey"></vue-recaptcha>
<input name="recaptchaResponse" v-model="recaptchaResponse" v-validate="'required'" type="hidden" ></input>
```

Now the onExpired method is like the following:

```
onExpired: function () {
  this.recaptchaResponse = null
},
```

The captcha is working fine and it is showing the tick mark when clicked. Now when I click the submit button,some of the backend API calls are taking more than a minute to complete, but it has been completed well within two minutes. While waiting for the call to complete, it is showing a message that says Verification Expired. Check the checkbox again in the captcha. I am very much confused how this is happening and how can I prevent this.

I think the timeout period for reCaptcha is 2 minutes, but for me it is expired before that. How can I fix this ? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.